# C# Trying to create a timer. It doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
public class TimerCountdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    float currentTime = 0f;
    float startingTime = 70f;
    float hours = 0;
    float minutes = 0;
    float seconds = 0;

    [SerializeField] Text countdownText;

    void Start()
    {
        currentTime = startingTime;
        float hours = currentTime / 3600 ;
        float minutes = currentTime % 3600 / 60 ;
        float seconds = currentTime % 60 ;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentTime -=1 * Time.deltaTime;
        hours = currentTime / 3600 ;
        minutes = currentTime % 3600 / 60 ;
        seconds = currentTime % 60 ;
        countdownText.text = hours.ToString("00") + ":" + minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00") + " --- " + currentTime.ToString("0");
    }
}
```

So this is my function. When I run this in unity, the counting down works, but the conversion to minutes seem to be wrong. As in, when it gets lower, the minute doesn't change only every 2 minute (180s passes). Why is that? What am I doing wrong?
Also, if i increment this for 9000f (2h 30min), it does the same, even if its 59seconds, it still stays 30, instead of 29. Any help? Is there any mistake in my logic?

Comment: Did you debug through it?

Comment: IMHO your whole approach is wrong. Use the built-in `TimeSpan` type: `countdownText.text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(currentTime).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");` Also, what's up with the `1 *` in the `1 *  Time.deltaTime;`? What's the point of that?

Comment: The calculations you posted are broken, but they don't produce a two-minute error. I thought maybe I'd overlooked something, but I copied them into my own test program, and they produce the expected wrong values but not a two minute error. So whatever the issue is, it's caused by code you didn't share. Please improve the question.

Comment: This is the only code I have. @mjwills no I didn't yet... 
Time.deltaTime is for using real time. Otherwise it just counts drops too fast, not each second. I tried using the answer with (int) and it works almost fine, but for some reason if i do that, then its either 1 second too fast or too slow. So its not on point either

Comment: See my updated answer, you can use floats if you need to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that your float is getting rounded when you are converting it to a string.

If you take something as simple as 1 minute, 33 seconds = 93f and run your function you will get:

```
float floatTime = 93f;
var floatMinutes = floatTime / 60; // floatMinutes = 1.55
Console.WriteLine(floatMinutes.ToString("00")); // Outputs: 02
```

However if you are using integer math, the remainder is thrown away:

```
int intTime = 93;
var intMinutes = intTime / 60; // intMinutes = 1
Console.WriteLine(intMinutes.ToString("00")); // Outputs: 01
```

To make floats display property:

```
public void Update()
{
    currentTime -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    hours = (float)Math.Floor(currentTime / 3600);
    minutes = (float)Math.Floor(currentTime % 3600 / 60);
    seconds = currentTime % 60;
    CountdownText = hours.ToString("00") + ":" + minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + seconds.ToString("00") + " --- " + currentTime.ToString("0");
}
```

Comment: `floatMinutes = floatTime / 60;` isn't the calculation the OP is using. They use `minutes = currentTime % 3600 / 60 ;`, which would produce the expected value.

Comment: Actually, you are wrong, `currentTime % 3600` will give the remaining seconds, divided by 60 will give you a fraction that will round when you convert it to a string.

Comment: Perhaps I could use their code but I thought a simplified example might help to understand what is happening

Comment: _"will give you a fraction that will round when you convert it to a string"_ -- that's true enough, but the OP's problem has nothing to do with rounding. The rounding produces at worst a 0.5 minute error. The OP claims a **two minute** error.

Comment: The OP also claims there is 180 seconds in 2 minutes

Comment: Yup, they do claim that. The question is hard to understand. That said, reading your example again, I see what you are getting at, and while a half second error's not a problem, a half-minute error is (i.e. you're right about that much). Still, that's doesn't explain a **two minute** error.

Comment: I don't think there is a two minute error, I believe the OP is not understanding the results that he is seeing.

Comment: _"I don't think there is a two minute error"_ -- that's your prerogative, but for now, the OP is claiming there is. You should probably get that clarified before you claim to have an answer.

Comment: It is 1 minute error. Sorry! So what's happening, if I have for example 63 seconds, is, it displays 00:01:03. And when it finally reaches 59seconds, the counter displays 00:01:59. I was not right to say there are 2 minutes error, but one. Now, if i try your solution, converting the currentTime to int, then it works, although it has a 1 second margin error, as in, the timer shows 00:01:03 although the seconds are 62 actually.

Comment: Yes! It works now. Although, i'm confused on floats around here. Why did we need to use Math.floor in order to make it work? Is it because, as you said above, it rounds up the number? Thank you so much btw!!

Comment: It actually does the same as div, but for floats... i See

Comment: Yes, while 1 minute 29 seconds will round down to 1 minute and display properly, 1 minute 30 seconds will round up displaying 2 minutes, 30 seconds. `Math.Floor` is just removing the decimal portion on your float.

Answer (score 0):

> the minute doesn't change only every 2 minute (180s passes). Why is that?

There's nothing in the code you posted that would suggest a reason for the minutes value getting stuck for two minutes at a time (or three...180 seconds is three minutes, not two, so it's not really clear what you mean).

The author of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64760586) suggests that your description is simply wrong, and that there's not a two minute delay between changes in the minute value. Their assumption may or may not be correct; it's hard to tell, given the wording of the question.

That said, it seems to me that your whole approach is wrong anyway. Doing all this math is pointless, given that .NET has very good support for dealing with time values built-in. I would change your code to look like this:

```cs
public class TimerCountdown : MonoBehaviour
{
    float currentTime = 0f;
    const float startingTime = 70f;

    [SerializeField] Text countdownText;

    void Start()
    {
        currentTime = startingTime;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        countdownText.text = $"{TimeSpan.FromSeconds(currentTime):hh\\:mm\\:ss}" + " --- " + currentTime.ToString("0");
    }
}
```

The above also uses string interpolation for the string formatting. This may or may not be available in the version of Unity3d you're using. If not, you can use the older `ToString()` approach:

```
countdownText.text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(currentTime).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss") + " --- " + currentTime.ToString("0");
```